# Warning: simplexml_load_file failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, xml

На локальной машине всё прекрасно работает, но залив на хостинг возникают ошибки:

> `Warning: simplexml_load_file(файл) [function.simplexml-load-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in корневой/fori.php on line 6`
> `Warning: simplexml_load_file(файл) [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "файл" in корневой/fori.php on line 6`

Код, помимо всяких там функций (их пробывал убирать, теже ошибки):

```
simplexml_load_file('файл');
```

Я так понимаю, мне не хватает прав, а как мне повысить свои права, если это так?) Вожусь 2-й день и, как обычно, у меня у одного такая ситуация, поэтому в поисковых системах ничего нужного не нашёл...

**Добавлено.**

Вот путь

> `server:8081/interfaceX1.php?
> query=X1NFTF9fcGFja29kLF9zdXJuYW1lLF9uYW1lLF9wYXJuYW1lLF9iaXJ
> 0aGRheSxfYXJlYV9fSVpfX2tsaWVudHNfd2hlcmVfcG9saXNudW09JzE0MjY4MjInX2FuZF9hcm
> VhI5456J19hbm34XJlYV9pc19ub3RfbnVs34gfYXJlYSE9JzI4J19hbmRfYXJlYSE9JzI5Jw==
> &sign=8214b0eb0fff3698d39a6b4765fd528d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Откройте доступ на чтение и запись к файлу и папке с которыми работаете.

Comment: Поставил 777, таже ошибка

Comment: поставьте 0666

Comment: Ну а почему же на локалке и на некоторых хостингах работает?

Comment: можно дать права только для владельца (0600)

Comment: для файла в котором вызывается simplexml_load_file('файл'); я поставил 0666 - не работает.

Comment: действительно странно...
а может у Вас этот файл уже открыт (во время обращения)?
попробуйте открыть другой файл (копию данного) для проверки.

Comment: Да я пробывал всё убирать, оставалось только simplexml_load_file('файл');
Ошибка та же возникала...

Comment: Да и ещё: файл к которому обращаюсь через simplexml_load_file на сервере с портом 8081

Answer (score 1):

Права доступа на удаленном сервере ставятся на папки с файлами через ftp доступ с помощью Тотал командера.